# How can I have color highlighting for my SASS variables?

Tags: plugins, sass, package, sublimetext3

How can I have color highlighting for my SASS variables?

```
$black: #000000
h1
    color: $black
```

As you can see, I am not getting color for SASS variables.
[image: Example]

Answer (score 1):

I use Color Highlighter. Seems to work for my SASS variables just fine

https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Color%20Highlighter

Comment: It's not working for me, can you please check?
http://prntscr.com/hsexr5

PS: I have not made any change in package settings.
SASS file is being treated by the system as SASS.
I am using Sublime Text 3, Build 3143

Comment: You might try closing the program and restarting it. But then again, in checking my app, it doesnt show color on some variables on my sass pages either. It works on my variable page, works on my compiled CSS page, but doesnt work on my _pages to be compiled. I think it only shows colors on those variable that are actual hex numbers such as #330066

Comment: I have restarted the app. Its not even showing color to my hexa color codes
http://prntscr.com/htb30w

I am using Windows, Sublime Text 3, Build 3143